# while trying to open bootstrap modal, browser stops responding

Tags: javascript, html

when i click on button to open bootstrap modal. the browser stops responding. and after sometime it gives error saying unresponsive script. Could you please help me with this issue.

Comment: include bootstrap.min.js followed by jquery.min.js.Place these files and  your custom script  at the bottom of html (before body end tag).

Comment: i did include bootstrap.min.js and i have all my script files at the bottom. but still not working. i have icludede it this way:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>frontend/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>frontend/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>frontend/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>frontend/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: remove jquery.js,bootstrap.js file keep only jquery.min.js , bootstrap.min.js files.

Comment: i did try that still not working. when i click on button to open modal, it opens and stays open for hardly 2 seconds and than browser stops responding. i am getting this error : a script on this page may be busy or it may have stopped responding. following with the link of jquery.min.js

Comment: can you share your code or fiddle your code please

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have boostrap library called

Answer (score 0):

Keep these two files in bottom of the page. and check browser console is thre any error on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>frontend/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>frontend/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```